# Element not interactable / selenium / python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping, click

Intento hacer click en un botón que sale en un pop up al cargar una pagina y no soy capaz.

LLevo varias semanas intentándolo y estoy frustradísimo, cosas que he intentado:

- esperar a que el elemento cargue con todo tipo de código (WebDriverWait, expected_conditions, time...)
- maximizar ventana
- acction chains

Observaciones:

- el elemento no esta escondido
- selenium aparentemente lo localiza (además probé otros localizadores)
- me deja clicar si lo hiciese de manera normal

Código

```
mensaje=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@data-dismiss="modal"]').click() #elemeto en cuestión
```

Preguntas que he hecho:

```
print("Element mensaje is visible? " + str(mensaje.is_displayed()))  #NO

print("Element mensaje is activated? " + str(mensaje.is_enabled()))  #YES
```

[image: le quiero dar al leído]

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor mestra el código en la pregunta como texto (no imagen).

Comment: Si haz probado bien todo lo que mencionas. Sube el código de lo que ya probaste. Quizá hay algún problema del que no te percataste.

Comment: Hola mateo!
Como puedo ejecutar ese script?!?

Comment: También sube tu url para que podamos probarlo y código.

Comment: el problema es que es una página privada por lo que no puedo subir la url

Answer (score 0):

¿Realmente necesitas cliquear el botón?¿Lo único que quieres es quitar el modal?

Si la respuesta a la última pregunta es **no**, llama manualmente a la función `leido` que el inspector indica en el evento `click` del botón.

Puedes hacerlo mediante javascript. Así:

```
driver.execute_script("leido()")
```

O si llamar manualmente a la función no quitara el modal, puedes crear un script que lo haga. Del mismo modo, lo ejecutarías con selenium mediante la función [`execute_script`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=Execute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script).

Comment: he probado con esto pero no da resultado...
`mensaje = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@data-dismiss="modal"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", mensaje)`
@Mateo

Comment: ¿Probaste `driver.execute_script("leido()")`?  Sino haz un script que borre el modal. Suponiendo que `div.modal-dialog` cotuviese todo el modal, puedes hacer un script que lo borre ([`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) u oculte (estableciendo la propiedad css `display: none`).

Comment: Si, probe `driver.execute_script("leido()")` , lo pegue tal cual pero no quita el modal, sin embargo la consola no me tira ningún mensaje (ya no pone element no interactable pero sigue sin funcionar).
Voy a probar con un script que borre el modal como dices a ver si lo consigo!!

Comment: Perdona @Mateo podrías escribir esos script que dices?
que me esta costando hacerlos

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo por aquí una solución:

```
aceptar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button')
aceptar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Saludos.

Edito: el problema no era este, si no más complejo, la solución que he puesto es relativamente trivial y reconozco haber hecho el ridículo. Un saludo comunidad.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eso no me sirve, como ya comenté anteriormente eso ya lo probé, la solución es más compleja.
De todas maneras muchas gracias raimin!

Comment: Tiene razón Jaime, es lo mismo que has hecho pero de una forma un poco diferente. De hecho he probado su código y sí me funciona correctamente.

Comment: Tiene razón Jaime, es lo mismo que has hecho pero de una forma un poco diferente.